# Show alert if a UITableView has no entries

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uitableview, ios5

In my iPad app, if on a UITableView there are no entries or all cells are empty, and if a particular button is pressed, there should be an alert. What could be the condition to check if all cells are empty in UITableView?

Thanks and regards

PC

Comment: Provide some code please. How do you put data into your tableview ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the count of your datasource.

For instance, if you are using an array `myArrayData`:

```
if ([myArrayData count] == 0) {
    // Do code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Adam Johnson's answer

If your data come from the **Core Data** and you're implementing a `NSFetchedResultController`

```
if ([self.fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects count] > 0) {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"UIAlertView"
    message:@"My message" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
    otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the viewWillAppear method to check your requirements.

If your button is pressed (I assume on a different view controller?) you may want to actually set a BOOL when the button is pressed and have a reference to that in this view controller.

And generally table views use an array (or some object) to hold their values, you could simply check to see if (myarray.count > 0) to see if you will have any table cells.

If you leave more information about your setup I would be happy to be more specific to your needs. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you use CoreData, you can detect the number of rows written to your table by numberOfRowInSection follows

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [[self.fetchedResultsController sections] objectAtIndex:section];

    if (sectionInfo.numberOfObjects == 0) {

              //Here you can use your code
    }

    return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, you could just enumerate through all the cells and see if they contain anything. For example:

```
BOOL isEmpty = false;
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:1]];
// Then depending on what kind of value you have in it...
if (cell.textLabel.text == @""){
// Keep going through the enumeration until there's actually something and then set isEmpty to true!
}
```

Comment: This is a terribly inefficient way to do it. These cells are generated from a Datasource, the datasource should be check, not the view it created.